# Extending Swift type with method that requires a generic

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods

My question is about extending a type with a method that requires a generic.

I want to extend `IndexPath` and add a method to check if it's valid in a given `NSFetchedResultsController`. Here's my extension:

```
 public extension IndexPath {
    func isValid(in fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>) -> Bool {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections,
        section < sections.count,
        item < sections[section].numberOfObjects else {
            return false
    }
    return true
 }
```

In my `UICollectionViewController` class, I declare `myFetchedResultsController`:

`private var myFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyModel>!`

`MyModel` is a `NSManagedObject`.

However, when I try to call my new method:

`indexPath.isValid(in: myFetchedResultsController)`

I get an error:

**Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchedResultsController!' to expected argument type 'NSFetchedResultsController'.
Insert ' as! NSFetchedResultsController**

What am I missing? `MyModel` is `NSManagedObject` so why is it asking me to cast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quicker than I thought. It turns out that changing the signature to include `<T: NSManagedObject>` fixes it:

`func isValid<T: NSManagedObject>(in fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<T>) -> Bool`